How to convert odds ratio to cohens d
I want to calculate the cohens d from adjustad OR, but I think I'm doing something wrong.
If aOR = 1.79, N = 600, N_case = 298, N_control = 302, then
is the cohen's d 0,139 or 0,321?
What formula did you use, what did I do wrong?
Thank you in advance <3

Hi Brandy. You ask what you did wrong, but you don't provide details indicating how you ended up with these two different results for $d$. So it's not possible to tell you where you made a mistake, if any, unless you edit your question to add this missing information.
